# issue with basic operations (strings)

Tags: java, string, netbeans

I'm a newbie in java and as far as I concern this is pretty to do simple but I don't remember exactly the synthax I need to apply in order to get what's next:

I have the following string:

```
Random sentence with a few words
```

I want a proper synthax which returns the following:

```
Random-sentence-with-a-few-words
```

Thanks.

Comment: replace whitespace with hyphen? There is a `String.replace()` method for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a replace

```
Use replace() to replace specifics words in your string:
MyString.replace(' ', '-');
```

Here you need specify 2 chars (the original value and the second parameter the value to replace)

You can read more about it [here](http://java-spain.com/metodos-replace-replacefirst-y-replaceall-y-expresiones-regulares)

Answer (score 3):

Use [`String#replace(char, char)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(char,%20char)):

```
myRandomStringWithSpaces.replace(' ', '-');
```

Edit: Used chars instead as per linked javadoc